# The database is case sensitive in unique constraints but not in select

Tags: sql-server, collation, case-sensitive

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and in the installation wizard I select the collation `Modern_Spanish_CS_AS`.

When I create a new database if I go to the properties of the database, I can see that the collation is correct, `CS_AS`.

However, when I do a select is not case sensitive and if I create a unique constraint I can't insert for example this strings: `user01` and `User01` because really the database is case insensitive.

Why if the server, the database and the table are case sensitive, the selections and the constraints not? In practice, is case insensitive.

How can I solve this problem? I would like that all the database was case sensitive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at this forum post and validate that the fields in your unique constraint are truly case-sensitive:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/6de23802-eb3b-4759-9d4d-a796c69e6271

You can query for the collation of the field (in case the table was created case-insensitive):

```
select      name, collation_name
from        sys.columns
where       object_id in (select object_id from sys.objects where name = '<table name>') and name = '<field name>'
```

Post back if this doesn't resolve the issue and I can add some tests.